# Passing const object reference to functor

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to create a map of input event objects to std::functions. The input event object has the == operator defined, but since map by default uses < to check for equality and my uses don't require sorting, I want to set the compare function to a functor that calls the == operator. Essentially, I want to do this:

```
#include <map>

struct Vertex
{
    int x;
    int y;

    constexpr bool operator==(const Vertex& v)
    {
        return (x == v.x) && (y == v.y);
    }
};

struct vertexCmp
{
    bool operator()(const Vertex& v1, const Vertex& v2)
    {
        return v1 == v2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Vertex, int, vertexCmp> _vertexMap;

    Vertex v;
    v.x = 1;
    v.y = 1;

    _vertexMap[v] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get a the following compiler error:

```
main.cpp||In member function ‘bool vertexCmp::operator()(const Vertex&, const Vertex&)’:|
main.cpp|21|error: passing ‘const Vertex’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
main.cpp|11|note:   in call to ‘constexpr bool Vertex::operator==(const Vertex&)’|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I know you can't call non const member functions on a const object but you would think constexpr would satisfy that requirement right? I feel like I'm overthinking my approach here and there's a better way to structure this.

Comment: `constexpr` and `const` are different kinds of "constantness". `constexpr` is for expressions which might be constant at compile time. `const` disallows modification of values at runtime. Just add `const` to your `operator==`

Comment: It doesn't matter if *you* don't require sorting. `std::map` requires sorting in order to work properly. And it can't do it with an equality comparison. If you make a hash function, you could use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: I like the idea of using a hash function and unordered_map a lot actually, I think that's a much better approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11, `constexpr` on a non-static member function implied a `const` function, but not in C++14 (because it was discovered there are actually use cases for a function that is `constexpr` where `*this` is not `const`).  You need

```
constexpr bool operator==(const Vertex& v) const
```

Comment: Can you give a link to that discovery? Would make your answer perfect ;)

Comment: Although I'll implement Benjamin Lindley's suggestion instead of my original approach, thank you for answering the question. I do have one follow up though, would making the operator constant cause issues when using it on non const objects?